# trying to add a uibarbuttonstyleCamera to a uitableviewcell in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

Im trying to add a uibarbutton- Camera style to a uitableviewcell programmatically like so
but I dont see anything in the uitableviewcell

```
UIButton *newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera];
        [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,10,50,30)];
        [newBtn addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [newBtn setEnabled:YES];
        [cell addSubview:newBtn];
```

but when I use this code, I see a rounded rect button in the uitableviewcell

```
  UIButton *newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,10,50,30)];
        [newBtn addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [newBtn setEnabled:YES];
        [cell addSubview:newBtn];
```

Is there any way I can add a uibarbuttonstyle button or all I can do is add a uibutton rounded rect style to the uitableviewcell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` is not the same as `UIButton`. It doesn't even inherit from `UIView`, so you can't add it as a subview to other views. What happens when you call

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera]
```

is that the `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera` constant is of an invalid value for `buttonWithType:`, so UIButton can't decide which type of button to return - probably it just returns an empty, not configured one or `nil`.

So there's no easy solution to your problem. What you can do is, for example, take a screenshot of the Camera bar button item, then extract its image using some kind of image editor application, then set that image as the image of a custom `UIButton` like this:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
```